# Why might stylesheets disappear from iframe after loading?

Tags: css, forms, iframe

I have a few iframes which don't appear to be formatting correctly. They format fine when opened as a stand alone page.

As far as I can tell, the stylesheets load, but then are removed from the iframe.

In the sources tab I can see the full stylesheet loading:

``
`

```
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-O8whS3fhG2OnA5Kas0Y9l3cfpmYjapjI0E4theH4iuMD+pLhbf6JI0jIMfYcK3yZ" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

    <!-- Form Styles -->
    <style>
        @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,500,600,700,700i");
        
        html {
          font-size: 16px;
        }`
```

``

In the console this is what is showing:

```
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        

        <!-- Font Awesome -->
        

        <!-- Form Styles -->
```

It is also momentarily showing up correctly but then quickly reverting to having no CSS, meaning it is loading but then being removed somehow.

The same template for the iframe forms is used elsewhere and is working correctly.

I've used difference checkers to find differences between the iframes that are working and those that aren't, and I can't see anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the `<!-- Bootstrap -->` comment coming from? Is it a part of your code that might be causing the issue?